# extracting bound function with this keyword out of addEventListener

Tags: javascript, leaflet, this, addeventlistener

I want to modify a [library function](https://github.com/Wildhoney/L.Pather/blob/6ad9a10525023b8e1a8518e1ed034cd249ecdb04/module/Pather.js#L325-L344) that looks like follows:

```
this.map.getContainer().addEventListener('touchstart', this.fire.bind(map, 'mousedown'));
```

Right now (if I get it right), the function listens for touch events and if they occur, dispatches corresponding mouse events. So it tells the map object to handle touch events just as mouse events.

```
this.map.on('mousedown', this.eventHandlers.mouseDown);
this.eventHandlers = {
    mouseDown: this.events.mouseDown.bind(this),
};
```

I want to modify the above function so it distinguishes between single finger touch events and multitouch events, like this:

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart);
function onTouchStart(e) { 
    if (e.touches.length > 1) { foo() } else { this.fire.bind(map, 'mousedown') }
};
```

However, it doesn't work with just putting the above listener function in there. I tried using e.currentTarget and also creating a var otherThis = this and then replacing this with otherThis, but it didn't work.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
>       at HTMLDivElement.onTouchStart

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You do not need to translate touch events into mouse events (`touchstart`→`mousedown`, `touchmove`→`mousemove`, `touchend`→`mouseup`) or viceversa: **the browser already does that for you**.

I strongly recommend you watch the ["Getting Touchy" presentation from 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBdQkhm1DvI) as well as reading the [corresponding slide deck](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/getting-touchy-presentation/#). It explains in depth how different browsers dispatch mouse (and pointer) events alongside touch events.

Even if you're dispatching `mousedown`/`up`/`move` only on some condition for the touch events, you'll be receiving *duplicate* `mousedown`/`up`/`move` events for a single touch.

---

On the other hand: A clean way to bind event handlers here...

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart);
function onTouchStart(e) { 
    if (e.touches.length > 1) { foo() } else { this.fire.bind(map, 'mousedown') }
};
```

...would be...

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart.bind(this));
function onTouchStart(e) { 
    if (e.touches.length > 1) { foo() } else { this.fire('mousedown') }
};
```

Note how the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) call is applied to the event handler function, and **not** to function calls inside the event handler. This makes the value of `this` inside the event handler become the parameter of `bind()`.

"The Leaflet way" would be...

```
L.DomEvent.on(element, 'touchstart', onTouchStart, this)
```

...which is a couple of wrappers over `bind` and `addEventListener`. `L.DomEvent` also handles browser quirks (`dblclick` on touchscreens under some circumstances), and translates non-standard IE10's `MSPointerDown` (et al), so that `touch*` events on a Win7 machine with IE10 and a touchscreen will work.

Comment: Thank you so much, @IvanSanchez. The library (linked in comments) does it this way and it seems to work, so I didn't want to redo the whole thing. But if I get some time, I'll have a look into the material you linked. Thanks for the detailed explanation, really helpful!

Comment: In that case, I must guess that the author of `L.Pather` is unaware that touch events also trigger mouse events automatically, but `L.Pather` suffers no ill effects from duplicate handling of such events :-/

Comment: Hi @IvanSanchez, just a quick question: I noticed that, when running my Cordova app in browser, LPather polylines become visible as you draw them during mousemove but on my Android device, they only become visible after mouseup. Could this be caused by the way L.Pather treats touch events?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
function onTouchStart(e) { 
    if (e.touches.length > 1) { foo() } else { this.fire.bind(map, 'mousedown') }
};
```

Problem is `this.fire.bind(map, 'mousedown')`. This code has no side effects it just defines a function. See [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). But doesn't actually call it.

To call it you can use:

```
this.fire('mousedown');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @eguneys. The thing is, I only replaced the code in the first snippet with the last snippet in my question, so I'd expect it to work without calling it explicitly? I don't fully understand the code but I guess it's done at some point in the code already. The library in question is [this one](https://github.com/Wildhoney/L.Pather/blob/6ad9a10525023b8e1a8518e1ed034cd249ecdb04/module/Pather.js#L325-L344). And I totally forgot to mention the error I'm getting, sorry! Updated the question.

Comment: Do not forget the ambiguity of `this`.